# Why did Allah create so many galaxies, planets and other astronomical phenomenas?

Tags: quran, hadith, sunnah, universe

When we consider the vastness of the universe, is there any other reason or purpose for its existence beyond people being reminded of Allah and praising Him for the beautiful things he has created?

Has any other purpose of these creations been mentioned in the Quran or hadith?

Comment: Are you asking about the purpose of the "vasteness" of the universe, or the purpose of the creation of the universe? These are 2 different but inter-related questions.

Comment: Not the creation of the universe, but the vastness of it. I already know the one core purpose of it but I was wondering if there was more to it than just pondering over it. Does it hint at the creation of other intelligent beings? Multiverse? Was there a need to make zillions of galaxies if it only served one core purpose? Jazakallah.

Comment: (2:164) (To guide) those who use their reason (to this Truth) there are many Signs in the structure of the heavens and the earth, in the constant alternation of night and day.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding about the vastness of the universe and the trillions of galaxies is part of Allah's creation plans. In this galaxy that we exist in, there could be thousands of other creations that Allah is testing them as well to move them forward closer to him, in the same way that we are tested here.
So yes, there are more purpose of this vast creation than being just for us to look at.

Comment: The thing is, it hasn't been mentioned anywhere about another creation. I think that all this is just knowledge only known to Allah.